# Python Passing Variables

Tags: python

I have this simplified code (the code I am working on is actually larger)...

```
def My_Age()
    Age = input ("What is your age")

def Message()
    print ("Your age is:", Age)

# Main program
Message()
```

My question is how do I get the value in Age to show in the message function?

Comment: your indentation is correct. Please make sure it appears in the question the way it appears in your editor.

Comment: The formatting's OK, but the indentation's wrong, as well as the function definition syntax.

Comment: There is a preview of what will be shown right below the edit box; you can look there to make sure the formatting’s correct.

Comment: You need to read the python tutorials on Functions and Passing Parameters. This is most definitely covered in many books and online tutorials.

Comment: To get a value out of a function you use `return`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget ':' for the function

```
def My_Age():
    Age = input ("What is your age? ")
    return Age

def Message():
    print ("Your age is: " + str(My_Age()))

# Main program
Message()

# Output:
# What is your age? 15
# Your age is: 15
```

**Edit** with parameters:

```
def My_Age():
    Age = input ("What is your age? ")
    return Age

def Message(age):
    print ("Your age is: " + str(age))

# Main program
Age = My_Age()
Message(Age)
```

Comment: Why the random default value that borders on personally identifiable information?

Comment: Because everyone should have this age? I'll edit right away, since it is indeed uncessary...

Answer (score 0):

```
def My_Age():
    # No need a variable
    return(input("What is your age? "))

def Message():
    print ("Your age is: {}".format(My_Age()))

# Main program
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    Message()
```

It's better to have this `if (__name__ == '__main__'):` statement before your main program so that you can call the function in this script from other functions. Check this out
[What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variable :

```
def My_Age():

        global Age
        Age = input ("What is your age")
def Message():

        My_Age()
        print ("Your age is: "+ Age)
Message()
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you've been looking?

```
def My_Age()
    Age = input ("What is your age")
    return Age

def Message()
    print ("Your age is:", My_Age())

# Main program
Message()
```

Comment: The question wanted parameters, I believe

Comment: Doesn't seem like that to me.

Comment: The word "passing" does heavily imply parameters

Comment: The question wanted the Age variable in the Message function, not call the other function